# CD with data not opening in selected application

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applications

I am hainvg a problem with an app called Reunion 9. My dad made me a CD/GED file with data from his PC and I'm trying to load it onto my MacBook Pro. When it initially opened, it gave the screen to choose an app. I clicked Adobe, but that won't work. Now, I can't get back to that screen to try something else.
It automatically goes to Adobe and tells me it won't work.

Got any suggestions for how to return to the application selection screen and what application I should select?

Comment: What is a CD/GED file?

Answer (score 2):

it's reasonably simple to change the default application (the process is quite similar to that on windows)

- Use Finder to find the file you are trying to open.
- Right Click (or Ctrl left Click) Choose "Open With" -> "Other"
- Use the resulting finder window to find the application you want to open the file with (you may need to change the "Enable" drop down to "All Applications")
- Tick the checkbox, "Always open with"
- Click "Open"